# Launching an App from Custom URL from Safari not working as intended in iOS >12.3

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

We share the App deeplinks (Universal links) with our users over email, sometimes they get wrapped by email service providers for safety.
When user taps on these wrapped deeplinks, instead of opening the App directly it opens the url in Safari.

We have a page hosted on that url. We capture the deeplink there and try to open the App using Custom URL scheme (myurlscheme://). But if the App is not installed, we try to redirect the user to the App Store page.

It all worked okay until now, but seems like Apple made some changes in Safari in the new versions of iOS (>12.3).
What’s happening now is, if the App is installed and we open the App from Safari (from Custom URL), the App Store page opens in a split second after opening our App.

This is the Javascript code that we are using:

```
window.location.href = 'myurlscheme://';
setTimeout(function() {
   window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/id123456789?ls=1&mt=8";
}, 500);
```

Is anyone else experiencing this. If yes, were you able to find any solution?

**Update:**
If we set the timeout to 4000 (i.e. 4 seconds), then it does not redirect to the App Store after launching the App.

Comment: why you don't try https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links they should handle any change much faster than you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @m1sh0 , but I was kind of hoping to do it without using a 3rd party service.

Comment: totally understand you, but sometimes it is easy to use something which is created and it is proven. Fingers crossed that you can solve your problem.

Comment: set timeout to 4000 is also work for me